# Preserving a query result for the duration of the query in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j 3.5.2 Desktop with Nodejs. I am trying to update a user record properties and add/remove relationship with other nodes in same query:
my query look like this:

```
 MATCH (user:Dealer {email: $paramObj.email})
 SET user += apoc.map.clean($paramObj, ["email","vehicles"],[])
                    WITH user, $paramObj.vehicles AS vehicles
                    UNWIND vehicles AS vehicle
                    MATCH(v:Vehicles {name:vehicle}) 
                    MERGE (user)-[r:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(v)
                    ON CREATE SET  r.since = timestamp()
                    WITH vehicles,user
                    MATCH (user)-[r:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(v)
                    WHERE NOT apoc.coll.contains(vehicles,v.name)
                    DELETE r
                    WITH $paramObj.email AS dealeremail
                    MATCH (user:Dealer {email: dealeremail})
                    RETURN user
```

The issue I am having is the return of  empty 'user' array when a query related to  deleting a vehicle relationship (r) result in zero rows.

How do I preserve the original 'user' result or save the email address to redo the query. I tried using WITH $paramObj.email AS dealerEmail but it seems that I cannot forward the dealerEmail...Thought I could.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is as a result of returning zero rows so it dawned on me that the OPTIONAL MATCH would also return a NULL result but with a single row with null values. So I change the  MATCH searching for a relationship to delete to an OPTIONAL MATCH.

```
  MATCH (user:Dealer {email: $paramObj.email})
  SET user += apoc.map.clean($paramObj, ["email","vehicles"],[])
                        WITH user, $paramObj.vehicles AS vehicles
                        UNWIND vehicles AS vehicle
                        MATCH(v:Vehicles {name:vehicle}) 
                        MERGE (user)-[r:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(v)
                        ON CREATE SET  r.since = timestamp()
                        WITH vehicles,user
                        OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(v)
                        WHERE NOT apoc.coll.contains(vehicles,v.name)
                        DELETE r
                        RETURN user
```

This did the trick

Comment: Looks good, though you might consider `RETURN DISTINCT user` if you only want to return each user a single time.

Comment: good point...though in this use case there can't be two of them.

Comment: It definitely looks like there can be multiple, especially with the unwinding of vehicals and your optional matches, as multiples on any of those will result in returning the same user multiple times. There's no resetting of cardinality here (aggregations or DISTINCT). Please review the kb article on [understanding cardinality in cypher](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-cypher-cardinality/).